# WooCommerce product sorting, remove one argument Sort by price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce and on products page my sorting is like this
[image: my current site]

I dont want last two sorting,
Sort by price : low to high & 
Sort by price : high to low

please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following CSS to your stylesheet

```
.orderby > option[value^="price"] {
    display: none;
}
```